# How to test the expectation on the eventSpy

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I am trying to test a backbone.model when saving.
Here's my piece of code.
As you can see from the comment there is a problem with `toHaveBeenCalledOnce` method.

P.S.:
I am using jasmine 1.2.0 and Sinon.JS 1.3.4

```
    describe('when saving', function ()
    {
        beforeEach(function () {
            this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
            this.responseBody = '{"id":3,"title":"Hello","tags":["garden","weekend"]}';
            this.server.respondWith(
                'POST',
                Routing.generate(this.apiName),
                [
                    200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, this.responseBody
                ]
            );
            this.eventSpy = sinon.spy();
        });

        afterEach(function() {
            this.server.restore();
        });

        it('should not save when title is empty', function() {
            this.model.bind('error', this.eventSpy);
            this.model.save({'title': ''});

            expect(this.eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce(); // TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toHaveBeenCalledOnce'
            expect(this.eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(this.model, 'cannot have an empty title');
        });
    });
```

---

console.log(expect(this.eventSpy));

[image: asddas]

Comment: this is a duplicate of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851167/test-the-rendering-of-a-backbone-view - only the context of the test has changed, while the error you are getting remains the same. please don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: @DerickBailey thanks for your comment. Indeed I am going to delete the previous question because I suppose this is more clear.

Comment: thanks ... looking for a way to remove my vote to close, but don't see one.

Comment: I posted my answer below, but on a related note, is there a reason you are attaching everything to `this`? It seems like you're just cluttering things up doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Jasmine has no function `toHaveBeenCalledOnce`. You need to check the count yourself.

```
expect(this.eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(this.eventSpy.callCount).toBe(1);
```

So I guess in your case, you'd want this:

```
expect(this.eventSpy.callCount).toBe(1);
expect(this.eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(this.model, 'cannot have an empty title');
```

#### Updated

The error you are getting now, "Expected a spy, but got Function" is because of exactly that. You are using a Sinon library Spy, and passing it to a Jasmine function that expects a Jasmine Spy.

You should do either:

```
this.eventSpy = jasmine.createSpy();
```

or

```
expect(this.eventSpy.calledOnce).toBe(true);
expect(this.eventSpt.calledWith(this.model, 'cannot have an empty title')).toBe(true);
```

What was your reasoning behind using Sinon along with Jasmine? I'd recommend the first solution, since then Jasmine will have more info to show when the test fails.

Comment: thanks, `expect(this.eventSpy.callCount).toBe(1); ` works fine. About `expect(this.eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith` I got the following error: `Expected a spy, but got Function.` how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.eventSpy)` and confirm that there us actually a Spy there?

Comment: The error refers to the argument I am passing toHaveBeenCalledWith, because `expect(this.eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith` is defined

Comment: Actually this.model in my case is an instance of Backbone.Model

Comment: The error is with `this.eventSpy`, it just only checks the type when you call toHaveBeenCalledWith. I updated my answer. Where are you setting `this.model` and `this.apiName`?

Comment: Thanks for your time: can you run in your js console the following lines and tell me if you get the same error? `var eventSpy = sinon.spy();
var model = new Backbone.Model();
expect(eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(model, 'cannot have an empty title');`

Answer (score 1):

There's a library called [jasmine-sinon](https://github.com/froots/jasmine-sinon) that adds sinon-specific matchers to jasmine.

It allows you to do things like

```
expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledBefore(myOtherSpy);
expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the [toHaveBeenCalledTimes](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber) method:

```
expect(this.eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```